# Random polygon shapes on HTML5 Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm still very new to the canvas element and I'm trying to draw random polygon shapes (triangular shapes) in random places on the canvas element. But I have trouble getting my head around it.

I have this so far, which draws a ploygon nicely, but how to add the randomness and positioning completely eludes me

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
if (c.getContext) {
  c2 = c.getContext('2d');
  var width = c2.width;
  var height = c2.height;
  var maxAmount = 20;

  for (i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {
    var polySize = 50;
    var posx = (Math.random() * (width - polySize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * (height - polySize)).toFixed();

    c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.moveTo(posx, posy);
    c2.lineTo(100, 50);
    c2.lineTo(50, 100);
    c2.lineTo(0, 90);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.fill();
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c" \>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to get the width and height properties of the `Context2D` property of your canvas, which both returned `undefined`.
What you need instead is the `canvas` element's width and height properties.

Now, since your comment to the other answer, if you need to move the whole shape, just use the first point you saved in `posx` and `posy` variables and then adjust the other points positions :

```js
var c = document.getElementById('c');
c.width =500;
c.height= 500;
if (c.getContext) {
  var c2 = c.getContext('2d');
  var width = c.width;
  var height = c.height;
  var maxAmount = 20;

  for (var i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {
    var polySize = 50;
    var posx = (Math.random() * (width - polySize));
    var posy = (Math.random() * (height - polySize));

    c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.moveTo(posx, posy);
    c2.lineTo(posx+100, posy+50);
    c2.lineTo(posx+50,posy+100);
    c2.lineTo(posx+0, posy+90);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.stroke();
    c2.fill();

  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"><\canvas>
```

Comment: Doh! How stupid am I. That makes total sense! Thanks!

Comment: Btw, If I can trouble you, the polygons are now all the same, how can I add some random shapes in the mix?

Comment: No trouble at all, simply call `Math.random()`on every point definition.

Answer (score 0):

Here canvas width and height properties are not set. so when invoke code following line of code, it returns NaN

```
var width = c2.width;
var height = c2.height;
```

To get random position try following code base

```
<canvas id="c" width="250" height="250" \>

var c = document.getElementById('c');
if (c.getContext) 
{
  c2 = c.getContext('2d');
  var width = c.width;
  var height = c.height;
  var maxAmount = 5;

  for (i = 0; i < maxAmount; i++) {
    var polySize = 50;
    var posx = (Math.random() * (width - polySize)).toFixed();
    var posy = (Math.random() * (height - polySize)).toFixed();

    c2.fillStyle = '#f00';
    c2.beginPath();
    c2.moveTo(posx, posy);
    c2.lineTo(100, 50);
    c2.lineTo(50, 100);
    c2.lineTo(0, 90);
    c2.closePath();
    c2.fill();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering but your code doesn't position the polygon on a different spot, just one point of the polygon. That was the problem  I was having as well

Comment: The problem is not that width and height aren't set but more that OP tried to get the ones from context2d which are undefined. If no width nor height are defined on the canvas object, default 300*150 is returned